# Oracle SQL: Display single columns from multiple rows of a single table with Logic

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL

I would like to look-up data from 2 rows of the same column from the same table together in an existing long query with multiple joins.

Current table set-up (single table):

```
Table: ACCOUNT_DETAILS
| TRX_ID | TYPE | FAC_ID | ACC_ID |
| ------ | ---- | ------ | ------ |
| 1234   | CRDR | ABC123 | AB1234 |
| 1234   | DBTR | XYZ222 | XY9800 |
| 9876   | CRDR | EFG999 | EF7659 |
| 9876   | DBTR | ABC123 | AB9900 |
```

Expected Result:

```
Table: REPORT
| TRX_ID | Counterparty FAC_ID | Counterparty ACC_ID |
| ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1234   | XYZ222              | XY9800              |
| 9876   | EFG999              | EF7659              |
```

Logic needed:
If FAC_ID NOT LIKE 'ABC%' then refer to the Counterparty FAC_ID (e.g. for TRX_ID = 1234, it will refer to the DBTR FAC_ID and DBTR ACC_ID; TRX_ID = 9876, it will refer to the CRDR FAC_ID AND CRDR ACC_ID)

Example:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'DBTR' AND FAC_ID LIKE 'ABC%' THEN (SELECT FAC_ID FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS WHERE TYPE = 'CRDR') 
ELSE (SELECT FAC_ID FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS WHERE TYPE = 'DBTR') END)
FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS
```

I've tried options such as JOINs, UNIONs and subqueries but it does not work. I would like to have the Counterparty FAC_ID and Counterparty ACC_IDs in separate single lines in the query, as I will include it in a long query that I already have.

Comment: Considering you are not using the type can you disregard it, is the fac_id the only restriction since you can just select the 3 columns with fac_ud not like 'ABC%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use CASE in a CTE to flag the rows where FAC_ID does not start with "ABC" and then use the flag in the WHERE clause.
See *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a76a5538ed73d39f757d4d0666fe0c9f)* for schema.

```
with cte as 
(
select 
TRX_ID,
FAC_ID,
ACC_ID,
CASE WHEN FAC_ID LIKE 'ABC%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ordinal
FROM ACCOUNT_DETAILS)
SELECT
TRX_ID,
FAC_ID,
ACC_ID
FROM CTE
WHERE ordinal = 1;
```

```
TRX_ID | FAC_ID | ACC_ID
-----: | :----- | :-----
  1234 | XYZ222 | XY9800
  9876 | EFG999 | EF7659
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a76a5538ed73d39f757d4d0666fe0c9f)*

Comment: Thanks for this! However, is there a simpler alternative? I was hoping to include this query to a longer query with existing joins from other tables. (for example, SELECT TRX_ID, FAC_ID, ACC_ID FROM TABLE_D INNER JOIN TABLE_E ON TABLE_E.ID = TABLE_D.ID)

Comment: You could use the query in the CTE as a sub-query with an alias and include where ordinal = 1 in your where clause (or having if regroupement). A row-level sub-query would avoid a CTE but would slow things down.